# SQL Server stored procedure pausing every 75 records from C# SqlClient

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a stored procedure which basically selects from a complex view joined with a few other columns.  When running the stored procedure through SSMS, it takes about 6 seconds to return a couple thousand rows, but running it with the exact same parameters from C# takes over a minute.

I added logging as it retrieved each record, and it appears to be retrieving 75 records almost simultaneously, and then sitting there doing nothing for approximately 1.5 seconds, then 75 more rows.  More specifically, it's pausing every time it reaches 74 modulo 75, so at 74, 149, 224, etc.  The delays range from 1.2 seconds to 1.8 seconds.

Next I inlined the query from the stored procedure directly into the C# code, and the delays went away.  With the SQL inline instead of a stored procedure, it only takes 6 seconds to run.

The delays seem very oddly specific and completely mysterious.  This isn't just "this query is poorly optimized under this situation" or "there's way too much data".  None of the data comes in consistent increments of 3, 5, 15, or 75s.  None of the fields are bigger than about 30 characters, no varbinary(max) or varchar(max) fields, there are only about 12 fields, and about 2500 records.  The only reason it takes 6 seconds under proper conditions is because the view in SQL is so complex, not because it's overloaded sending back massive amounts of data.

Maybe all the following details are extraneous to the question, I'm mainly including them to make it clear that there's nothing unusual about any of the code involved.

Here's a general overview of what the C# code is doing (nothing special):

```
using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "myprocedure";
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@startValue", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@endValue", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = DBNull.Value;
    var result = new List<MyObject>();
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var myObj = new MyObject();
            myObj.Value1 = reader["Value1"] as string;
            myObj.Value2 = reader["Value2"] as int?;
            myObj.Value3 = reader["Value3"] as decimal?;
            result.Add(myObj);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In practice, the real code is a bit more complex, because it uses reflection the first time it's called to build the setters for each of the fields being set:

```
(PropertyInfo property) =>
{
var param1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(t));
var param2 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
return Expression.Lambda<Action<t, object>>(
    Expression.Call(
        Expression.Convert(param1, property.ReflectedType),
        property.GetSetMethod(false),
        Expression.Convert(param2, property.PropertyType)),
    param1, param2).Compile();
}
```

But I'm certain it's not a problem with those setters, because the C# code is use very extensively, and this is the only database call where this 1.5 second delay occurs.

The database query looks something like this when inlined, and the stored procedure is pretty much identical:

```
DECLARE @startValue varchar(20) = NULL
DECLARE @endValue varchar(20) = NULL

SELECT MyView.*, OtherTable.Name
FROM MyView
INNER JOIN OtherTable ON MyView.PK = OtherTable.PK
WHERE (MyView.Value3 > 0 OR MyView.Value4 > 0)
AND (@startValue IS NULL OR MyView.Value1 >= @startValue)
AND (@endValue IS NULL OR MyView.Value1 <= @endValue)
```

What could be causing a ~1.5 second delay in the reader every exactly 75 records?

Comment: "With the SQL inline instead of a stored procedure, it only takes 6 seconds to run." Smells like a problem with parameter sniffing (pardon the pun). First of all, [don't use `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), specify the parameter types explicitly (even for `NULL`). Second, read [this](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html), you may have a bad execution plan on your hands (with various fixes). Executing the statement separately is *not* the same thing as executing it in a stored procedure.

Comment: Sorry, the AddWithValue was just a shortcut to demonstrate what it's doing, that's not real code.  All parameter types are being determined and set properly via reflection.  Also, I'm aware of parameter sniffing, and that it leads to bad query optimization.  This problem does not appear to have anything to do with SQL's internal query optimization, because of the very specific and strange behavior described in my question.

Comment: If different execution plans end up being used (and I see nothing in your question disproving that hypothesis, notably, no actual execution plans) then this can result in different rates of speed in row production. At first I thought you could have a network issue, but the fact that the execution speed differs based on whether the statement is separate or in an sproc (and not on client vs. server code) is a very, very strong indicator that that is *not* the issue, because (presumably) the data returned is exactly the same in both cases (although you do not specify if you've verified this).

Comment: If you'd like to play with the network transfer hypothesis, try adding `Packet Size=32767` to your connection string. I strongly suspect this will have no significant effect on the total execution time, but you may observe the delays shifting.

Comment: What is the database doing differently in both cases?  If you run a detailed Profiler/XEvents trace, does it show different behavior?  Can you tell how wide the table rows are, and whether or not about 75 rows fit into a single page?  When it pauses, does sp_who2 show blocking?

Comment: I'll have to experiment with these things and see what I can find.  It might be a day or so before I get the chance to dig into it in depth.